# LWJGL/OpenGL get BufferedImage from texture ID

Tags: opengl, image

I have got a texture ID and would like to retrieve its data. The data should be stored in a `BufferedImage` for future use. I am using the LWJGL library in Java, so if there are some library-specific shortcuts I'd like to use them.

My naive approach is to first fill a buffer with the image data and then pass it to the image.

```
int id = ...;
IntBuffer buff = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1024*512*4);
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
System.out.println(buff.remaining());
GL11.glGetTexImage(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL12.GL_BGRA, GL12.GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, buff);
System.out.println(buff.remaining());
buff.flip();
buff.rewind();
System.out.println(buff.remaining());
// Somehow create a BufferedImage from buff here
```

I don't know why, but the first and to `buff.remaining()` return the same value, indicating that nothing has been written which should not be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it a more complete example, let's also consider loading a texture from a `BufferedImage` as well.

First let's assume:

```
int texture = glGenTextures();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
```

First we need to load an image. For this we can use `ImageIO.read()`. Then we put all the pixels from the `BufferedImage` into a `ByteBuffer`.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));
int width = image.getWidth(), height = image.getHeight();

int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);

ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(width * height * 4); // 4 because RGBA

for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        int pixel = pixels[x + y * width];
        buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));
        buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));
        buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));
        buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));
    }
}

buffer.flip();

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

Before we go ahead and call `glGetTexImage()` lets assume that the only thing we have is the texture name (`texture`). Thus we consider that we don't know the size or format of the texture. We can get all this by doing:

```
int format = glGetTexLevelParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
int width = glGetTexLevelParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH);
int height = glGetTexLevelParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT);
```

Using that information we again create a `ByteBuffer` as well as a `BufferedImage`. Reading the pixels from the `ByteBuffer` and placing them on the `BufferedImage`.

```
int channels = 4;
if (format == GL_RGB)
    channels = 3;

ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(width * height * channels);
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        int i = (x + y * width) * channels;

        int r = buffer.get(i) & 0xFF;
        int g = buffer.get(i + 1) & 0xFF;
        int b = buffer.get(i + 2) & 0xFF;
        int a = 255;
        if (channels == 4)
            a = buffer.get(i + 3) & 0xFF;

        image.setRGB(x, y, (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b);
    }
}
```

Now go ahead and save that `BufferedImage` to a file.

```
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("out.png"));
```

Last but not least, you can get rid of all those `GL11.` prefixes, by statically importing `GL11`. You do that by doing:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
```